# Can't write in a sqlite3 Database

Tags: sqlite, eclipse-plugin, ormlite, osgi-bundle

I have a program that uses a sqlite3 database,i can read but not write it,this problem appears only in my computer. In the rest of computers (Same OS) it works OK.

I have ubuntu 11.10 64 bits and Eclipse Juno as an IDE.

If I open it with sqliteMan and try to insert manually it works. It only occurs when I try to write through a osgi bundle.

The database permissions : -rw-rw-r-- .

The database mapping is done with OrmLite.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get when attempting to write? If no error, do you commit a transaction, if any?

Comment: There is no error to show,all bundles active and no exception. But when you see the database table its empty. The transactions do not appear in my log but i insist that with the same code is working in other computers.

Comment: This is ORMLite the Java ORM right?  Can you turn on logging for ORMLite?  That will tell you what commands are being executed at least.  Make sure you are logging all of the your exceptions.  See: http://ormlite.com/docs/logging